# Transform a nonconvex constraint into a convex one

Tags: convex-optimization

I am solving an optimization problem and I need to formulate it as a convex optimization problem. Is there any way to write the constraint 
$$
1 - e^{z} - \frac{e^{-r}}{1+r} \leq 0
$$
as a convex constraint?

Comment: both $z$ and $r$ are optimizing variables? Or one is a constant?

Comment: Yes, both z and r are optimization variables.

Comment: Without any additional restrictions on $r$ it is impossible. Even if you said, say, $r>-1$, there is no guarantee. You could perhaps do a change of variables $\tilde{z}=e^z$ and $\tilde{r}=e^r/(1+r)$, but then it's quite likely your problem is not convex in these variables, either.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answers. Actually, variables $r$ and $z$ have the following restrictions: $r > 0$ and $z \leq 0$. Making a change of variables could work but, as you say, this  affect the convexity of the objective function and other restrictions.

Comment: Your model is simply not convex, then.